# Using IAsyncCollector<T>.AddAsync() with Table Storage in a loop does not save

Tags: azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have a v3 azure function with a HttpTrigger and Table paramater. I am trying to loop over a `List<Job>` and add them to table storage. Below doesn't throw any errors but also does NOT save any data.

```cs
    [StorageAccount("connectionStrings:tables")]
    [FunctionName("GetTmsJobData")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
       [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
       [Table("previouslyseenjobs")] IAsyncCollector<Job> jobsCollector)
    {
        //...get list
        foreach (Job job in Jobs){
            await jobsCollector.AddAsync(job);
    }
```

Yet, if I `new` up a `Job` and have a single call to `jobsCollector.AddAsync()` it works.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a DateTime property which during deserialisation was being set to 0001-01-01 00:00:00 which is invalid for table storage.